# ADB не видит тэгов Unity

Tags: android, unity3d

Телефон `Meizu MX6` обновился с глобальной прошивкой `Flyme 7.0.0 / Android 7.1.1`, до этого стоял `Android 6`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при `adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG` или `adb logcat Unity:* Ads:* *:S` получаю следующее и больше ничего:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при обычном `adb logcat` при запуске игры не вижу логов от `Unity`, только `libc-netbsd`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `Android monitor` таже самая ситуация, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой ?

Драйвер на `adb` для модели телефона ставил, пишет что последний драйвер уже установлен на ваш ПК. Я в отчаянии) делать откат на `Android 6` не хочется

Comment: А если дебажить через Android Studio, то тоже самое?

Comment: Да, пробовал фильтра ставить и выбирать разные типы Debug, Error и т.д.

Comment: Т.е, когда в Android Studio в logcat вы не указываете фильтры или указываете "unity", то логов игры нету? о_О

Comment: да) вообще нету, думал может с проектом что, пробовал другие запускать, тоже не видит

Comment: Я похожее видел на huawei. У них в настройках телефона есть пункт, в котором можно отключить логи. Может у вас что-то похожее на телефоне есть?

Comment: Подобного не нашел, некоторые функции включил, но результатов это не принесло